# Why is my Kivy application not getting lat and lon from Android?

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I am writing an Android app that gets the weather from the nearest weather station based on the user's location. I am having trouble getting Kivy to get the location from the user's phone. Below is my code.

I have the appropriate permissions set in my buildozer.spec file to request GPS location.

Permissions from my buildozer.spec file
android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

```
import requests
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDTopAppBar
from kivy.utils import platform

KV = '''
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "Wing Calculator"
        right_action_items: [["rotate-3d-variant", lambda x: app.clear_inputs()]]

    MDLabel:
        id: conditions_label
        text: "Current Conditions"
        halign: "center"
        valign: "middle"
        theme_text_color: "Secondary"

    MDTextField:
        id: weight_input
        hint_text: "Weight"
        helper_text: "Enter weight in pounds"
        helper_text_mode: "persistent"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: "200dp"

    MDLabel:
        text: "Beginner"
        halign: "center"

    MDSwitch:
        group: "skill"
        id: skill_switch
        value: "Beginner"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

    MDLabel:
        text: "Small Wing Preferred"
        halign: "center"

    MDSwitch:
        group: "style"
        id: style_switch
        value: "Less power"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Calculate"
        on_release: app.wing_calculator()
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
'''


class WingCalculatorApp(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.winddirection = None
        self.windgust = None
        self.wind = None
        self.locationname = None
        self.lon = None
        self.lat = None

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'BlueGray'
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = 'A700'
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Light'
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def clear_inputs(self):
        # Access the root widget or any other widget that contains the text inputs
        root_widget = self.root

        # Find all text input widgets using the `walk` method
        text_inputs = [widget for widget in root_widget.walk() if isinstance(widget, TextInput)]

        # Clear the text in each text input widget
        for text_input in text_inputs:
            text_input.text = ''

    def on_start(self):
        self.runGPS()
        self.gps_location()
        self.get_wind()
        self.currentconditions()
        self.display_conditions()

    def runGPS(self):
        if platform == 'android':
            from android.permissions import Permission, request_permissions
            
            def callback(permission, results):
                if all([res for res in results]):
                    print("Got all permissions")
                    from plyer import gps, android
                    gps.configure(on_location=self.gps_location,
                                  on_status=self.on_auth_status)
                    gps.start(minTime=1000, minDistance=0)
                else:
                    print("Did not get all permissions")

            request_permissions([Permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                                 Permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION], callback)

    def gps_location(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.lat = kwargs.get('lat')
            self.lon = kwargs.get('lon')
            print(f"GPS position {self.lat}, {self.lon}")
            
            if self.lat is None and self.lon is None:
                self.lat = 21.5155198
                self.lon = -87.6696238
                print("Latitude and longitude not found in GPS data.")
            return self.lat, self.lon

    def on_auth_status(self, general_status, status_message):
        if general_status == 'provider-enabled':
            pass
        else:
            self.open_gps_access_popup()

    def open_gps_access_popup(self):
        dialog = MDDialog(title="GPS Error", text="You need to enable GPS access for the app to function properly")
```

I have to add more text because my post is mostly code.

Comment: _Specifically_, what does "not getting location" mean? Do you get an error? Some invalid or null value? Please read [ask].